# Appcelerator Titanium Failed to parse app's Info.plist

Tags: parsing, titanium, appcelerator, info.plist

Failed to parse app's Info.plist error. Is there someone know this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SDK 5.5.0 or later for Xcode 8+ and iOS 10+. There was a breaking change in that releases so the CLI was updated to incorporate this changes. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete **Build** & **Resources** folders from root of the project. (These folders might not be there)
2. Clean the project and re-run the app, it should work.

If this doesn't work then there could be some other issues for which you need to provide more info on what stuffs are you using related to Info.plist file.

Comment: it did not work. My Appcelerator Version is 4.7, Titanium SDK is 5.1.GA

Comment: Are you using something different in your tiapp.xml file? 
I would recommend you to suggest the Appc Studio to latest and Ti SDK to 5.5.1.GA or 6.0.0.GA (if you are not going to use some modules which won't support Ti 6).
Are you using simulator or device?
Also provide more info on tiapp.xml.

Comment: I'm trying to run it on IOS Simulator. When i update, my app is giving error a lot of code lines.